# Trying to submit form and use onclick at the same button click

Tags: javascript, printing, submit

I'm trying to print a PDF file (onclick) and count the click at the same button (submit).
what i want is on the click to view the print job and than submit the form, maybe to make a delay between them?

```
<form method="post">
<button type="submit" onclick="printJS({printable:'graphics/babushka/frog.pdf', type:'pdf', showModal:true})" name="print" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="outline: 0;"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a normal (non submitting) button and submit the form (& run the print function) with javascript's `element.submit();` as below:

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
<button type="button" onclick="printJS({printable:'graphics/babushka/frog.pdf', type:'pdf', showModal:true});document.getElementById('myForm').submit();" name="print" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="outline: 0;"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button>
</form>
```

If you want a delay you can use `setTimeout` to provide the delay

```
<form id="myForm" method="post">
<button type="button" onclick="printJS({printable:'graphics/babushka/frog.pdf', type:'pdf', showModal:true});setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById('myForm').submit();}, 1000)" name="print" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" style="outline: 0;"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button>
</form>
```

Where `1000` is the delay in milliseconds